# How can I put the block I am looking at into my inventory?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've seen someone on bedrock look at a block and then get the block in their empty slot hand. Can you do that without a mod?

Answer (score 1):

The keybind depends on which platform you are playing on.

I believe on Xbox this is undefined by default. You can go into your key bindings in Settings (Controls) and change 'Pick Block' to the desired key. Then whenever you press this button, it will change the selected block on your hotbar with the one you are looking at.

Comment: Just a JSYK: on a computer, it defaults to "Mouse Button 3" or "middle mouse" button.